# JSF grid and cell fusion

Tags: jsf-2, grid, primefaces, html-table

I'm doing a jsf project with jsf2 (mojarra) and primefaces (2.2RC2).

I have a list of objects to display on two columns and X rows.

But for some items, I want to display them on two columns, to make a colspan.

Is it possible with primefaces in some components or with jsf impl ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the PrimeFaces showcase it is possible with a [PanelGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/panelGrid.jsf). Unfortunately it is available only in the 3.1 version. I had to use html table tags to do this.